# How to find the closest city using android geolocation to get the weather data

Tags: android, react-native, android-location, openweathermap

I'm making a weather forcast app for my uni project and I wonder how to get the name of the  closest city so I can get the weather data from sites like OpenWeatherMap, is there maybe other site that can return the data of the city that is closest to me?

Comment: check new solution

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Using LocationManager, get the lat, lng of current location.

LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

2. Use Geocoder api, to fetch the address list based on your current lat, lng.

Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), 
 location.getLongitude(), 1);
if (addresses.size() > 0) {
    for(Address adr : addresses){
     if(adr != null && adr.getLocality().length() > 0){
       cityName = adr.getLocality()
        break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down problem as below:

**1. Request User location coordinate**

With Geolocation API you can request user location. For sake of simplicity, let we use EXPO SDK as it provides a unified API for common tasks.

```js
import * as Location from "expo-location";

export const hasLocationServiceEnable = async () =>
  await Location.hasServicesEnabledAsync();

const getUserLocation = async () => {
  let result = null;
  const isLocationAccessEnabled = await hasLocationServiceEnable();

  if (!isLocationAccessEnabled) {
    return result;
  } else {
    let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== "granted") {
      return result;
    } else {
      try {
        let { coords } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        result = coords || null;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      return result;
    }
  }
};

export default getUserLocation;
```

**2. Geocode coordinates to physical address names**

Geocoding requires third-party services, let us use  [Google Map Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) and has [react native wrapper package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geocoding).

```js
import Geocoder from "react-native-geocoding";


// Initialize the module (needs to be done only once)
Geocoder.init("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); // use a valid API key

export const getPlaceFromCoordinate = async ({ longitude, latitude }) => {
  let place = null;
  const response = await Geocoder.from(
    parseFloat(latitude),
    parseFloat(longitude)
  );
  address = response.results[0].formatted_address || null;
  return address;
};
export default getPlaceFromCoordinate;
```

**3. Request place weather data**

```js
export const WEATHER_API = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=${"YOUR_OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY"}&units=metric`;


export const getWeatherForecast = (place) => {
  const requestUrl = `${WEATHER_API}&q=${place}`;
  let forecast = null;
  try {
    const todayForecast = await fetch(`${requestUrl}`);
    forecast = await todayForecast.json();
    return forecast;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return forecast;
  }
};
```

**4. Connect all together**

```js
const getPlaceWeather = async () => {
  try {
    const coordinate = await getUserLocation();
    if (!coordinate) return;
    const place = await getPlaceFromCoordinate(coordinate);
    if (!place) return;

    const placeForecast = await getWeatherForecast(place);

    console.log({ placeForecast });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

This is a high-level solution, there are a lot of features, I didn't cover including show weather icons, weather widget, and more.